# Python: pop item in list of lists by index

Tags: python, list

I have to remove an item in a list of lines by index of which item of `lines[0]`  not in headers.

The input is as follows:

```
headers = ['internal_id', 'default_code', 'ean13', 'supplier_id', 'product_qty']
lines = [['default_code', 'fld_code', 'test'],[1212, 4545, 'test1'],[45, 787, 'test2']]
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
lines = [['default_code'],[1212],[45]]
```

What I have tried to do so far is here:

```
for x in lines[0]:
    if x not in headers:
        for line in lines[0]:
            line.pop(line.index(x))
print lines
```

This has not produced the required output. Please help with this.

Comment: Since you corrected language Kevin Cruijssen, I don't understand... For me "The expected output" is not compatible with the explaination "I have to remove an item in a list of lines by index of which item of lines[0] not in headers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My correction based of your codes:

```
for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(lines[0]))):
    if x not in headers:
        for line in lines:
            line.pop(i)
print lines
```

Output:

```
[['default_code'], [1212], [45]]
```

Comment: Jo, i have edited my answer. It will loop the lines[0] reversed and work with more than 2 elements. But when the question is marked as answered, you shouldn't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension (you could also use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)).

```
lines = [line for line in lines if line[0] in headers]
```

Output:

```
[['default_code', 'fld_code']]
```

If what you want is a "manual" loop use [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
for x in lines:
    if x[0] not in headers:
        lines.remove(x)
```

Comment: @ I need remove missed item in lines[0] comparatively with headers, as well as all lists in lines by same index of missed item index of lines[0].

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use pop, you have to use indices and then it is better to start by end to have no indice problem.

```
for x in range(len(lines)-1,-1,-1):
    if lines[x][0] not in headers:
        lines.pop(x)     
print lines
```

I don't know what is your project but you should consider the use of a dictionnary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you wanted to write :)

```
for x in lines[0]:
    if x not in headers:
        n = lines[0].index(x)
        for line in lines:
            line.remove(line[n])
print lines
```

you were kind of close. you don't want to use pop, if you want to 'remove' an element at a certain position. there are more elegant and shorter solutions, but this one suits your coding style. take a look at list comprehension in python, it's pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for line in lines[0]:
        line.pop(line.index(x))
```

I hope in that for loop line is holding value of string type. we cannot use pop with string. correct me if am wrong.